# How to place 'not' reasonably in a clause?

Tags: difference, phrases

Is it true that we often use 'not' with a verb or auxiliary verb  i.e. 'not to do', 'do not need to do'? 'not' does not have this limitation when it forms a fixed collocation with other words, such as 'not...but...', 'not only... but also...'

> 1. The second fact is that many linguists work **not** just on languages
>    other than English **but** on languages which have been little studied
>    or not studied at all.
> 2. If this project fails, it will affect **not only** our department, **but also** the whole organization.

But I came across this sentence today.

> a. In the discussion of (3) above, we observed that, although we
> analyse clauses and sentences individually for convenience, in real
> language they **do not occur in isolation but** as part of longer texts.

In my view, it should be

> b. In the discussion of (3) above, we observed that, although we
> analyse clauses and sentences individually for convenience, in real
> language they **occur not in isolation but** as part of longer texts.

What's the difference between *a* and *b*? Is *a* formal?

Comment: If you can accept "Shakespeare was not [only] a writer...", why can't you accept "In real language they do not occur in isolation..."?

Comment: Both constructions are perfectly valid, but your "negated adverbial clause" revised version *(they occur **not in isolation** but as part of longer texts)* strikes me as significantly more "literary, poetic" ("formal"?) than the original "negated **verb**" version *(they **do not occur** in isolation)*. In conversational contexts *I don't want this, I want that* is quite natural, but *I want not this, but that* is just weird.

Comment: @Kate Bunting To precisely express my intention, I have changed the example.

Comment: I agree with the others that your version is more formal, but not the only correct one.

Comment: @Kate Bunting  The first example is not proper too. A better is 'In the discussion of (2a–c), we saw that (9) relates **not** to Frank bought a piano for Jane **but** to Frank bought something for Jane. [Jim Miller. (2002). An Introduction to English Syntax. p.30.]'

Comment: The first example is perfectly proper.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Yes, but it is not what I really want to express.

Comment: The verb should be: do not work. Very simple. Or you can use the other structure, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your re-written version is missing some punctuation:

> in real language they occur, not in isolation, but as part of longer texts.

Now that you're talking about something occurring (as opposed to '*not* occurring') you have a created a contrasting element that needs to be offset from your main statement about what *does* occur.

Yes, they are two ways of saying the same thing, but grammatically different. The original version is effectively "*not this, but that*", and your version is saying "*this (and, parenthetically, not that*"). The way you suggest is not exactly more "formal", but lends itself better to the written word than the spoken. When speaking extemporaneously, we tend to tag exceptions and contrasting elements to the end of a statement.